# Force needle plot to show all x-labels

Tags: r, plot

I have the simple following plot:

```
success<-0:12
plot(success,dbinom(success,size=12,prob=0.8),type="h",main="Distribution binomiale (n=12,p=0.8)",
ylab="Probabilité",xlab="success",lwd=3)
```

How to force all x-labels to appear? Actually its displays only even values.

I don't want to use ggplot for this if possible.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `xaxp` argument to specify the start of the tick marks, the end of the tick marks and how many spaces are in between.

```
success<-0:12
plot(success,dbinom(success,size=12,prob=0.8),type="h",main="Distribution binomiale (n=12,p=0.8)",
     ylab="Probabilité",xlab="success",lwd=3,
     xaxp = c(0, 12, 12))
```